# cant change localIdentName in nuxt.config.ts

Tags: nuxt.js

im trying to change **localIdentName** in **nuxt.config.ts** but it doesn't work

based on nuxt version 3 docs i add the following code to my **nuxt.config.ts** .

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    webpack: {
        loaders: {
            cssModules: {
                modules: {
                    localIdentName: "[local]_[hash:base64:15]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

but it doesn't change anything at all